# How to find similar elements from lists and merge them into one list in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{'similar_record_id': ['A-1','A-2','A-3','A-4','A-5'],

 'idx_pair' : [[25, 26],[835, 836],[834, 836, 835],[67, 69, 68],[62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65]
  
}
```

Here idx_pair will have a list of lists, here some of pairs are similar to another list of elements as follows -

[835,836] is existed in this [834,836,835] so merge it as [834,835,836]

[67,69,68] is existed in this [62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65] so merge it as [62,68,66,69,67,65]

If any of element from a list is existed in another list they should be merged.

expected output as:

```
{'similar_record_id': ['A-1','A-2','A-3'],

'idx_pair' : [[25, 26],[834,835, 836],[62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65]
  
}
```

Comment: Can an element in a list exists in multiple (more than 2) lists?

Comment: Yes. if an element is exist in any other list they should be merged.

Comment: What about `similar_record_id`? Is there any requirement for the relations between `similar_record_id` and `idx_pair`, or just 'A-n'?

Comment: @holydragon Yes there is a relation: like 'A1' has [25,26] 'A-2' has [835, 836] and 'A-5' has [62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65]

Comment: @I'mahdi OK I'm not familiar with this networkX

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia like -- how do you know that it is going to be ['A-1','A-2','A-3'] instead of ['A-1','A-3','A-5'] for the example above?

Comment: My bad. what ever the similar idx code would be. it should be unique over there. even if it is A1, A-3, A-5 that would be FINE.

Comment: Why is A-3 in the output? Shouldn't it be A-4

Comment: `tmp = dict(zip(*d.values())) ; result = dict(zip(('similar_record_id', 'idx_pair'), zip(*((k, v) for k, v in tmp.items() if not any(set(v).issubset(s) for s in tmp.values() if s != v)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using graph theory, via [`networkx.connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#connected-components):

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

data = {'similar_record_id': ['A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', 'A-5'],
        'idx_pair': [[25, 26], [835, 836], [834, 836, 835], [67, 69, 68], [62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65]]}

# a dict to speed up search of idx_pairs by similar_record_id
lookup = {k: set(v) for k, v in zip(data["similar_record_id"], data["idx_pair"])}

# create a graph with nodes from the values of data["similar_record_id"]
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(data["similar_record_id"])

# if two idx_pair share an element add and edge to the graph
for s, t in combinations(lookup, r=2):
    if lookup[s] & lookup[t]:  # if the intersection is not empty
        g.add_edge(s, t)

# from the connected components create the output
res = {}
for component in nx.connected_components(g):
    representative = min(component, key=data['similar_record_id'].index)
    union = set().union(*(lookup[c] for c in component))
    res[representative] = union

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'A-1': {25, 26}, 'A-2': {834, 835, 836}, 'A-4': {65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 62}}
```

The idea is to use [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) to find the `similar_record_id` values that should be merged together.

Comment: Fantastic. it works as expected. glad to learn new things.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness set arithemtics for this task as follows

```
data = [[25, 26],[835, 836],[834, 836, 835],[67, 69, 68],[62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65]]
merged = []
for d in data:
    d_set = set(d)
    for m in merged:
        if d_set.intersection(m):
            m.extend(d)
            break
    else:
        merged.append(d)
print(merged)
```

gives output

```
[[25, 26], [835, 836, 834, 836, 835], [67, 69, 68, 62, 68, 66, 69, 67, 65]]
```

Explanation: I prepare empty list `merged` then iterate over data and extend first list in merged which have any common item with currenctly considered element of data (i.e. where intersection is not empty set), if there is not such element in merged I append data element to merge. Note usage of `for-else` where body of `else` is executed iff `break` was not used.

Comment: OP's expected output needs `similar_record_id` as well.